# MySQL error on backtick symbol on INSERT when there isn't one

Tags: mysql

MySQL here. I'm trying to get an INSERT to work:

```
INSERT INTO users (
    user_ref_id,
    user_contact_info_id,
    user_secure_password,
    user_role_id,
    user_status_id
) VALUES (
    UUID(),
    SELECT ci.contact_info_id FROM contact_info ci WHERE ci.contact_info_email = 'admin@example.com',
    '12345',
    SELECT r.role_id FROM roles r WHERE r.role_label = 'ADMIN',
    SELECT us.user_status_id FROM user_statuses us WHERE us.user_status_label = 'ACTIVATED'
);
```

But I'm getting:

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'SELECT ci.contact_info_id FROM contact_info ci WHERE ci.contact_info_email = 'ad' at line 9
```

When I [Google MySQL 1064 42000 errors](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fix-error-1064-42000-while-creating-a-database-in-mysql#:%7E:text=The%20ERROR%201064%20(42000)%20mainly,in%20ERROR%201064%20(42000).) it just tells me that I have an error with my "backtick symbol" but I don't have those in my INSERT. Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?

Comment: Compiler , like me, is struggling to make sense of this mashup of values and select clauses. Sample data and expected outcome would help.

Comment: No worries @P.Salmon, another user was able to figure out easy peasy :-)

Comment: The SELECT statements in VALUES must be enclosed inside parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
INSERT INTO users (
    user_ref_id,
    user_contact_info_id,
    user_secure_password,
    user_role_id,
    user_status_id
) VALUES (
    UUID(),
    (SELECT ci.contact_info_id FROM contact_info ci WHERE ci.contact_info_email = 'admin@example.com'),
    '12345',
    (SELECT r.role_id FROM roles r WHERE r.role_label = 'ADMIN'),
    (SELECT us.user_status_id FROM user_statuses us WHERE us.user_status_label = 'ACTIVATED')
);
```

Each SELECT from VALUES should be enclosed in ().

Comment: Let's hope none of those sub queries returns more than 1 value.

Comment: @P.Salmon That's a whole different issue :), but good point.